# How to receive an email from users in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, send

I have a form that allows users to enter their names, email add, subject and message. When the user hits SEND, the message should be sent to me(admin).
I have this code under my development config...

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  # SMTP settings for gmail
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
     :address              => @user.email,
     :port                 => 587,
     :user_name            => ENV['sys.questdentalusa@gmail.com'],
     :password             => ENV['passwordhere'],
     :authentication       => 'plain',
     :enable_starttls_auto => true
 }
```

and this code under my user_mailer

```
def welcome_email(user)
  @user = user
  mg_client = Mailgun::Client.new ENV['api_key']
  message_params = {:from    => ENV[@user.email],
                  :to      => 'sys.questdentalusa@gmail.com',
                  :subject => @user.subject,
                  :text    => @user.text}
  mg_client.send_message ENV['domain'], message_params
end
```

It won't send the message. It's as if it did not execute.
The rule is, no model should be involved.
Example, you have an existing gmail account and wrote a message sent to me. I should receive your message from your entered gmail account.

Comment: `ENV[@user.email]` this looks like a bug.

Comment: The @user instance variable isn't accessible from within your dev config.  Also saying 'it won't send the message' doesnt give us anything to help you with.  Can you please post the stack trace.

Comment: @AllanWSmith there is no error. It's as if it does not execute

Comment: I hope those credentials you have listed above aren't actually correct for that email account...

Comment: @Slicedpan thanks...i actually posted the correct one but i edited it. anyway, that email is for testing only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for quite a while now and I just decided to might as well share it here. This is what I did in my development.rb

```
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: "gmail.com",
  user_name: "sys.questdentalusa@gmail.com",
  password: "passwordhere",
  authentication: :plain,
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

This is what I got under my Mailer

```
class MessageMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "sys.questdentalusa@gmail.com"
  default to: "questdentalusa@gmail.com"

  def new_message(contact)
    @contact = contact

    mail subject: 'Inquiry from website: ' + @contact[:subject]
  end
end
```

I got this under new_message.text.erb

```
Name: <%= @contact[:name] %>
Email: <%= @contact[:email] %>
Message: <%= @contact[:content] %>
```

And this is under my controller

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token
  def send_mail
    if MessageMailer.new_message(contact_params).deliver
      redirect_to contact_path
      flash[:notice] = 'Your messages has been sent.'
    end
  end
  private
  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :subject, :content)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things your `developer config` and  `message_params` looks wrong,

in `message_params` : `:from    => ENV[@user.email]` is should be like `@user.email`

in `smtp_settings` : `:address => @user.email,` is like `"smtp.mailgun.org"`. checkout more smtp_settings at [here](http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/handling-emails-in-rails)

Comment: I considered that link but it did not help.